# AspNetBoilerplate client side validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm trying out aspnetboilerplate and I love it so far. I downloaded the template with just ASP.NET Core MVC. The one thing I don't quite understand is when I have a Model class i.e.

```
public class CreateSubjektInput
{
    [StringLength(11), Required]
    public string Oib { get; set; }
}
```

When there is a Model error (e.g. stringlength  = 5) I get an `AbpValidationException` without even hitting the controller. So how to do client side validation like in aspnet core with jquery.unobtrusive? Or how to handle model errors? I read the documentation and I saw in sample projects the validation was in pure javascript. I'm lost here

Answer (score -1):

First, read this document:

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Validating-Data-Transfer-Objects

There are lot of different methods to doing this in ABP. Custom validation attributes, overriding existing modelState, jquery.unobtrusive, and etc.

Big part of validation code is here:

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/tree/dev/src/Abp/Runtime/Validation